# Graph automorphisms that preserve independent sets

Tags: reference-request, graph-theory, algebraic-graph-theory, automorphisms

Let $G=(V,E)$ be a graph and $\mathrm{Ind}(G)$ be the collection of its independent sets.

We call a graph automorphism $f:V \to V$ of $G$ *good* if it is non-trivial and $f(\mathrm{Ind}(G))=\mathrm{Ind}(G)$, i.e. $f$ maps every independent set of $G$ into another independent set of $G$.

(i) Is there a (elegant/minimal) set of conditions under on the graph $G$ that guarantees the existence of a *good* automorphism?

(ii) Is there any paper in the mathematical literature studying this class of *good* automorphisms?

Comment: Some graphs have trivial automorphism groups only.

Comment: What do you mean by "automorphism"?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the question depends on a misunderstanding of a standard term.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I thought that if $f$ is graph automorphism then it preserves both edges and non-edges. In that case, any automorphism would be good, and as @Turbo said, some graphs have trivial autormorphism groups only. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_automorphism